# How do you apply a function to a nested column using purrr::map, and output to a new column?

Tags: r, purrr

I'm new to purrr and tidyr in general.  I am trying to map a function to a nested column of datasets, and output as a new column in the main (nested) tibble.

Original attempt does run, but doesn't seem to apply the correct dataset to the functions.  When I run the function on an individual dataset from the datasets column it gives the correct results.  The function when run with all variables via map (see below for syntax used) gives different (incorrect) results.  I'm guessing I have the syntax incorrect and it is applying the function to the wrong dataset - but cannot figure out what the correct syntax should be.

dat is the original dataframe with two nested columns data=original dataset, datatidy=tidy dataset.  I would like to run a function on the datatidy column and output the results as a new (nested column) in dat.

```
  glimpse(dat)
        >  Observations: 535
        >     Variables: 4
        >     $ SITE_NO  <chr> "BC08EF0001", "BC08EF0001", "BC08EF0001", "BC08EF0001", "BC08EF0001", "BC08EF0001", "BC08EF0001", "B...
        >     $ variable <fct> CHLORIDE, FLUORIDE, SULPHATE, ALUMINUM TOTAL, ARSENIC TOTAL, BORON TOTAL, CADMIUM TOTAL, CHROMIUM TO...
        >     $ data     <list> [<tbl_df[234 x 15]>, <tbl_df[235 x 15]>, <tbl_df[234 x 15]>, <tbl_df[235 x 15]>, <tbl_df[235 x 15]>...
        >     $ datatidy <list> [<tbl_df[116 x 17]>, <tbl_df[116 x 17]>, <tbl_df[116 x 17]>, <tbl_df[116 x 17]>, <tbl_df[116 x 17]>... 
        > 
    
> glimpse(dat$dataTidy[[1]])
 $ DecDate        <dbl> 2005.047, 2005.121, 2005.195, 2005.312, 2005.392, 
 $ month          <dbl> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
 $ season         <fct> Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, 
 $ Value          <dbl> 0.5, 0.7, 0.7, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 
 $ Date           <date> 2005-01-18, 2005-02-14, 2005-03-13, 2005-04-25, 
 $ Value_subDL    <dbl> 0.50, 0.70, 0.70, 0.30, 0.05, 0.05,
 $ logConcVal     <lgl> FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 

    > results <- mutate(dat
    >         newcol = map(dataTidy, ~ EnvOut_fun(.x$Value_subDL, 
    >                                                        time = as.numeric(.x$Date), 
    >                                                        group = .x$season, 
    >                                                        time.name="as.numeric(Date)", 
    >                                                        group.name="season", 
    >                                                        y.name="Value_subDL", 
    >                                                        LOGY=.x$logConcVal)))
```

I tried the syntax in the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41617917/applying-functions-to-nested-dataframes-with-map) but cannot seem to get it to work.

> 

```
  dat %>% 
    mutate(newcolumn = map(dataTidy, ~ EnvOut_fun(.x[["Value_subDL"]],
                                                   time=as.numeric(.x[["Date"]], ...)))
```

**Example of EnvOut_fun.**

The function uses columns from dataTidy to run a seasonal kendall test, and saves the original (list results) as sk, and extracts some info into a dataframe.  A list containing sk and the EnvOut dataframe for each row in the main tibble should be saved to a new nested column.

```
EnvOut_fun <- function(y, time, group, 
                       time.name=NULL, group.name=NULL, y.name="y", 
                       LOGY=FALSE){
  
  y = if(LOGY==FALSE) {y}else{log(y)}
  y.name = if(LOGY==FALSE) { y.name}else{paste0("Log(", y.name,")")}
  
  sk <- EnvStats::kendallSeasonalTrendTest(y ~ group+time,  
                                           year.name="time", season.name="season", 
                                           data.name="y.name")

  EnvOut <- tibble(
     tau=sk$estimate[["tau"]],
     slope=sk$estimate[["slope"]], 
     int = sk$estimate[["intercept"]],     
     p_val_raw = sk$p.value["z (Trend)"],
     slope_p_val = p_val_raw,
     numSeas = length(sk$sample.size)-1  ,
     medOfData = median(y),
     medOfTime = median(time) ,   
     time.nm = time.name, 
     block.nm = group.name, 
     data.nm = y.name, 
     LogY = LOGY
  ) %>% 
    mutate(int_from_data = medOfData- (slope* medOfTime))

    sk <- list(sk=sk, EnvOut=EnvOut)
 sk
}
```

**EDIT**

Both syntaxes above work for applying a user defined function to nested dataframe.

Comment: I think you are on the right track with the pattern, but I can't wrap my head around the function you are trying to apply and what you expect that output to be, could you clarify?

Comment: @Nate - I've updated to include the EnvOut function and structure of the dataTidy dataframes.   I also realized some confusion may have also come from the fact that I was mapping 'datasets' in the 'dataTidy' (typo when I was trying to clean up the example).

Comment: What error message are you getting? My guess is the problem is related to how you are building the formula argument in `kendallSeasonalTrendTest`

Comment: Thanks @Nate.  I wasn't getting an error, but the results weren't mapping to the same order as the original dataframe input (i.e. the results for newcol[[1]] were not the results for the first variable (row) in dat.   I reran the entire code from the start and both syntaxes do seem to work on a subset of my data -  I can't seem to recreate the issue.  So perhaps I had something weird in my workspace at the time?   Anyways - it seems to work.  Thanks for the help!